# How to run an async function without blocking the execution in Django channels

Tags: python, django, async-await, python-asyncio, django-channels

I have an `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` running django channels for an online turn-based game.

There is need to verify that the player associated to the current turn is online, and if they aren't, the sever should wait 5 seconds to give the player a chance to come back before updating the turn and passing onto the next player.

At the end of the function that sends the new state to connected players, which is called every time the client sends the socket a message modifying the state, you have these two lines:

```
await self.send_new_state_to_all_players(event_specifics)
await self.check_current_player_online(game_id) # routine to handle the case where current player isn't online
```

The method `check_current_player_online()` does this:

```
async def check_current_player_online(self, game_id):
        current_turn_player_number = await self.get_current_turn(game_id)
        if await self.is_online(await self.get_player_id_from_number(game_id, current_turn_player_number)): # if current player is online, resume normal game flow
            return

        await asyncio.sleep(5)

        if not await self.is_online(await self.get_player_id_from_number(game_id, current_turn_player_number)): # if player hasn't come back, increment turn
            await self.increment_turn(game_id)
            await self.send_new_state_to_all_players({
                'type': 'pass_turn',
            })
```

Expected behavior: when the turn of a player who isn't online comes, every player should receive the new state sent by `send_new_state_to_all_players`, and be informed it's *xyz*'s turn (the offline player), then after 5 seconds, if *xyz* hasn't come back online, the socket should send a new `state` message after updating the turn.

Actual behavior: the intended behavior takes place for everyone *but* the last player who sent a message to the socket, which is the one who triggered the `check_current_player_online()`. They won't receive the first new state, and will only receive the updated state and the second updated state from `check_current_player_online()`, together, after 5 seconds, when the function has finished running.

Here's the implementation of `send_new_state_to_all_players` along with the handler it calls:

```
async def send_new_state_to_all_players(self, event_specifics):
        game_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['game_id']
        for player in await sync_to_async(list)(Player.objects.filter(Q(game_id=game_id))):
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.game_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'game_state_handler',
                    'player_id': player.pk,
                    'event_specifics': event_specifics,
                }
            )

# handler
    async def game_state_handler(self, event):
        if(self.scope['session']['player_id'] != event['player_id']):
            return
        state = await self.get_game_state(self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['game_id'], event['player_id'])
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type': 'new_state',
            'state': state,
            'event_specifics': event['event_specifics'],
        }))

# function called by the handler

@database_sync_to_async
    def get_game_state(self, game_id, player_id):
        # Returns a dictionary holding the game's state
        game = Game.objects.get(pk=game_id)
        
        this_player = Player.objects.get(pk=player_id)
        this_player_cards = CardsInHand.objects.filter(player_id=player_id)
        my_cards = []
        for card in this_player_cards:
            card_str = str(card.card_number) + card.card_seed
            my_cards.append(card_str)
        
        other_players_list = []
        other_players = Player.objects.filter(Q(game_id=game_id) & ~Q(pk=player_id))
        for player in other_players:
            player_data = {
                'number': player.player_number,
                'is_online': player.is_online,
                'number_of_cards': CardsInHand.objects.filter(player_id=player).count(),
                'name': player.name,
            }
            other_players_list.append(player_data)
        state = {
            'current_turn': game.player_current_turn,
            'last_turn': game.player_last_turn,
            'current_card': game.current_card,
            'last_card': game.last_card,
            'number_of_stacked_cards': len(json.loads(game.stacked_cards)),
            'last_amount_played': game.last_amount_played,
            'won_by': game.winning_player if game.has_been_won else -1,
            'my_cards': my_cards,
            'other_players_data': other_players_list,
            'my_player_number': this_player.player_number,
        }

        return state
```

Why does this happen? How do I make this process non-blocking or enforce that the first function be ran till the end before moving onto the second one?

Comment: Show the implementation of `send_new_state_to_all_players`

Comment: I edited my post to include it, thank you